# The most efficient way to encode Go structs as map keys in Protobuf

Tags: performance, go, protocol-buffers

As I understand, protocol buffers do not allow using a message (and therefore Go struct) as a key:

```
Key in map fields cannot be float/double, bytes or message types.
```

```
message HashCoordinate {
    int32 x = 1;
    int32 y = 2;
}
```

```
message State {
    map<HashCoordinate, Entity> entities = 1;
}
```

A workaround is to store the `HashCoordinate` key as a JSON string:

```
message HashCoordinate {
    int32 x = 1;
    int32 y = 2;
}
```

```
message State {
    map<string, Entity> entities = 1;
}
```

This is not as performant as storing a struct, for comparison purposes. Are there other options that are more performant that serializing the `HashCoordinates` into a string?

Comment: How focused are you on performance? (vs readability, ability to process protobuf in other languages etc). For example I wound expect a `uint64` key ([example encoding](https://play.golang.org/p/8Gd82UjV_rX)) to perform well but this sacrifices readability. Alternatively you could use a [nested map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863661/protobuf-nested-maps) but that requires two lookups. Perhaps benchmark a few alternatives with your data.

Comment: @Brits this should be the most efficient way. Thank you. I will not read the coordinates on a frequent basis so I think this is the best option.

Comment: @Brits can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends; how focused are you on performance? (vs readability, ability to process protobuf in other languages etc).

For example I would expect a uint64 key ([example encoding](https://play.golang.org/p/8Gd82UjV_rX)) to perform well but this sacrifices readability. Alternatively you could use a [nested map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863661/protobuf-nested-maps) but that requires two lookups. Perhaps benchmark a few alternatives with your data.

Be careful that you are not [optimising prematurely](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) - the downside of using either of the above approaches is that it is harder to read/understand the proto file. My default approach in this case would be to return a slice (so `repeated` in proto file) and convert it to a map upon receipt unless there was a compelling reason to transmit it as a map.